# Duplicate question with duplicate answer

Tags: support, questions, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I'm currently looking at a question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909797/change-the-background-color-keyboard-with-my-viewcontroller

Then I searched for a duplicate to the question and found this :

[How to change keyboard background color in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728847/how-to-change-keyboard-background-color-in-ios)

Now the problem isn't that the question is a duplicate (it is) but that the answer to the question is a direct copy of the answer of the duplicate question.

So I wondered if can you do that?

Comment: Flag it for mod attention, and make sure to include a link to the original post. I usually write something such as "Plagiarized without attribution from [link to original]". Mods will delete the post, and can suspend the user if it's a more widespread problem.

Comment: I have flagged it and the awnser is deleted, and put the link in the comments

Comment: Actually, the owner deleted the answer after seeing your comment.

Comment: Ah i did not know that